# SQL Syntax Issue in Sequencing Generation

Tags: sql, entity-framework, stored-procedures

I am currently working on a project that involves generating sequences using stored procedures in Entity Framework. I was using Code Project article [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33274/Flexible-numbering-sequences-in-T-SQL), and upon attempting to generate the following stored procedure, I received a syntax error:

```
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF

GO 
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO 

CREATE PROCEDURE DBO.p_GetNextInSequence 
    @SequenceKey VARCHAR(20)
AS 
BEGIN 
SET NOCOUNT ON 
DECLARE @LASTNUMBER INT
DECLARE @NEXTNUMBER INT
DECLARE @FORMATTEDNUMBER VARCHAR(40)
DECLARE @MYKEY VARCHAR(30)

IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 'X' 
              FROM SequenceControl 
              WHERE SequenceControl.SequenceKey = @SequenceKey )
BEGIN 
    SELECT    @SequenceKey AS SequenceKey, 
              CAST('' AS VARCHAR(30)) AS NextSequenceFormatted, 
              CAST(0 AS INT) AS NextSequenceInt 
    RETURN 
END 

DECLARE @SEQFORMAT VARCHAR(30), @IncrementBy INT, 
                   @IncrementStep INT, @zeropadtodigits INT

SELECT @SEQFORMAT = RTRIM(LTRIM(SequenceFormat)),
       @IncrementBy = IncrementBy, 
       @zeropadtodigits = ZeroPadToDigits 
FROM    SequenceControl 
WHERE    SequenceControl.SequenceKey = @SequenceKey 

DECLARE @THEROWCOUNT INT 
SET @THEROWCOUNT    = 0 

BEGIN TRANSACTION T1
    WHILE ( @THEROWCOUNT =0 ) 
    BEGIN 
        SELECT   @LASTNUMBER= LastSequence 
        FROM     SequenceControl
        WHERE    SequenceControl.SequenceKey= @SequenceKey 

        UPDATE     SequenceControl 
        SET        LastSequence = @LASTNUMBER + @IncrementBy 
        WHERE      SequenceKey = @SequenceKey AND    
                   LastSequence = @LASTNUMBER 

        SELECT @THEROWCOUNT = @@ROWCOUNT
    END 
COMMIT TRANSACTION T1 

--SQL Complains near this region...
DECLARE @FMTNUM VARCHAR(20) 
SET @NEXTNUMBER = @LASTNUMBER + @IncrementBy 
IF ( @zeropadtodigits>0) 
    SET @FMTNUM = ( REPLICATE('0', @zeropadtodigits) + 
                    CAST(@NEXTNUMBER AS VARCHAR(20)), @zeropadtodigits) 
ELSE 
    SET @FMTNUM = CAST(@NEXTNUMBER AS VARCHAR(10)) 


SET @FORMATTEDNUMBER = REPLACE(@SEQFORMAT,'[#]', @FMTNUM ) 

SELECT    @SequenceKey AS SequenceKey, 
          CAST(@FORMATTEDNUMBER AS VARCHAR(30)) AS NextSequenceFormatted, 
          @NEXTNUMBER AS NextSequenceInt 
END 

GO 
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER OFF
GO 
SET ANSI_NULLS ON    
GO
```

SQL is complaining about an incorrect syntax near `','` on Line 56:

```
DECLARE @FMTNUM VARCHAR(20)
```

However - I can't seem to figure out where or what is causing the issue. Also, if anyone has any suggestions or articles pertaining to using stored procedures within Entity Framework (*and returning output*) I would be appreciative.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual error is here:

```
IF ( @zeropadtodigits>0) 
    SET @FMTNUM = ( REPLICATE('0', @zeropadtodigits) + 
                    CAST(@NEXTNUMBER AS VARCHAR(20)), @zeropadtodigits)
```

More specifically, here:

`, @zeropadtodigits)`

That comma doesn't do anything, and `@zeropadtodigits` doesn't apply to anything either.  There's no function using that as a parameter inside the parentheses.

Comment: Thanks JNX - I wasn't sure why that was there. I kept reading over the article wondering if it would play any role.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax is actually blowing up at:

```
SET @FMTNUM = ( REPLICATE('0', @zeropadtodigits) + 
                CAST(@NEXTNUMBER AS VARCHAR(20)), @zeropadtodigits)
```

Why it's complaining at the other line, I don't know.

Comment: Thanks Scen - I had a suspicion that it was there, however I am not sure about that second @zeropadtodigits.